# How to dynamically lock the orientation of the ios Native app

Tags: ios

I am new to Objective c Native coding in IOS. I am having two buttons. One to lock  the app to portrait and another lock the landscape orientation. What should I do to achieve this. Locking in the sense it will fix to the locked side and will not turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i have used a method to implement the same using ios plugin which i created in worklight(For hybrid apps).

The function for setting the flag is

```
#import "HelloworlPlugin.h"

@implementation HelloworlPlugin

int count=0;



-(void)sayhello:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)option
{
    [arguments pop];
    NSString *responseString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

 if([responseString isEqualToString:@"1"])
 {
     count=1;
 }
    else
    {
        count=0;
    }
    NSLog(@"Zero %@",responseString);
}

-(int)count1
{
    NSLog(@"count= %d",count);
    if(count<1)
    {

        Cv=0;
    }
    else
    {
        Cv=1;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d",Cv);
    return Cv;


}

@end
```

Where in say hello function i get the arguments from the hybrid app and based on that i set the flag variable Cv to 1 or 0.

Below is the default method which i have changed little bit to do my implementation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    HelloworlPlugin *object=[[HelloworlPlugin alloc] init];

    int fValue=[object count1];

    NSLog(@"%d",fValue);
    if(fValue==1)
    {
    return (interfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

is a thing that is default function based on which the orientation is set returning true set all the orientation else by giving the approriate orientation we can set the answer.So here based on the cv value i stored in fValue i have locked the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

For example this way:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```